# How to use .then like .success?

Tags: angularjs

I have code like this. But thats return OLD token, although my server has NEW token.

```
function stores() {
    return $http.get(URL + 'stores').then(function(response){
        console.log(response.config.headers.Authorization);
    });
}
```

This code below return NEW token, as my server last generate. This is what i want.

```
function stores() {
    return $http.get(URL + 'stores').success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log(headers('Authorization'));
    });
}
```

The question is, how can i do this with .then method ? i look at $http doc, they said .success will depreceate

Comment: What's the ` URL` var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the way you're accessing the headers. The response object has the following properties ([from Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)):

- data – `{string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
- status – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
- headers – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
- config – `{Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
- statusText – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.

---

Access the headers like this:

```
function stores() {
    return $http.get(URL + 'stores').then(function(response){
        console.log(response.headers('Authorization'));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In pretty sure it because `.then` needs two call back function. One success and one error. Like so:

```
$http.get( URL + 'stores').then(function(res){

        $scope.var = res.data;

    },function(){})
```

Comment: It doesn't *need* the error callback. That's optional, if you feel the need to catch the error.

Comment: @dboskovic then something must be wrong with the URL

Comment: I think the assumption is that `URL` is set somewhere outside of the example. `response.headers('Authorization');` would likely resolve the issue.

Comment: Should I delete this answer?